# Find the general solution of a non homogenous linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question:
3 solutions of a certain 2nd order non homogenous linear equation are:
$$ψ_1(t)=t^2$$
$$ψ_2(t)=t^2+e^{2t}$$
$$ψ_3(t)=1+t^2+2e^{2t}$$
Find the general solution of the equation.

My attempt: (I closely followed an example from the book)

so $ψ_2(t)-ψ_1(t)=e^{2t}$
and 
$ψ_3(t)-ψ_2(t)=1+e^{2t}$
are solutions of the corresponding homogenous equation. Next I need to show that these are linearly independent in order to use the theorem to find the general solution. I assume they are, but I am not sure how to exactly show that?

And then using that theorem:
Every solution is in the form of $y(t)=c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)+ψ(t)$
so
$$y(t)=c_1y_1(t)+c_2y_2(t)+ψ(t)$$
$$y(t)=c_1e^{2t}+c_2(1+e^{2t})+t^2$$
$$y(t)=(c_1+c_2)e^{2t}+c_2+t^2$$

I am not really sure about my answer, particularly during the part of assuming linear independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: To check for Linear independence use the Wronskian which is defined as $$W[y_1\;\;y_2]=\text{det}\begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1 & y'_2 \end{bmatrix}=y_1y'_2-y_1'y_2$$ If the determinant is zero, what does that say about linear independence?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is easy enough to show linear independence, this problem can more easily be done directly.

By definition, a linear second order DE can be written as 
$$
y'' + f_1(t)y' +f_0(t)y = g(y)
$$
The fact that all the $\psi_i$ given satisfy the equation implies that 
$$ \left\{
\begin{align}
 2&+&2t&f_1(t) +& t^2f_0(t) &= g(t) \\
 2+4e^{2t}&+&(2t+2e^{2t})&f_1(t) +&(t^2+e^{2t})f_0(t) &= g(t) \\
 2+4e^{2t}&+&(2t+2e^{2t})&f_1(t) +&(1+t^2+e^{2t})f_0(t) &= g(t) \\
\end{align}
\right.
$$
Subtract the second from the third to get 
$$f_0(t)= 0$$
Substitute that, and subtract the first from the second to get
$$4e^{2t}+2e^{2t}f_1(t) = 0 \Rightarrow f_1(t) = -2
$$
Substitute that into the first equation to get 
$$2-4t = g(t)$$
So the linear differential equation with leading coefficient $1$ which has these solutions is 
$$
y''-2y' = 2-4t
$$
The corresponding homogeneous equation $y''=2y'$ has general solution $t=Ae^{2t}+C$
so the general solution to the inhomogenous equation is any one of the three particular solutions plus that, all of which simplify to 
$$
y = Ae^{2t} +t^2 + C$$